# General question about safety-critical use of microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller

I was wondering if microcontrollers that hobbyists use, such as the 8-bit Atmel AVR ATMega328 which is used in many of my small projects, can be used in sensitive things, for example a life-dependent application such as an aircraft of space shuttle?

I am asking out of curiousity: I am a student in school.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "hobby" microcontroller, just software written by hobbyists. The development process is what most standards, e. g. DO-178B, govern, not what hardware is used

Comment: I'm sorry but this is an enormously broad question, and in some places you are asking for opinions. That makes your question a poor candidate for this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson sorry for the questions if it bothered you but shall I delete or do what ?

Comment: You can check manufacturer website for which purposes a certain chip is meant for. It is not only a hobbyist toy, but most likely it is not meant for medical systems that support life, military or nuclear reactor kind of systems either.

Comment: This is a rather subjective question. Typically you would trust any product that you use because you have some type of... “faith” that the engineers who made the product of having the knowledge of knowing what they were doing. I can’t really give a probability of failure because that job belongs to quality control in engineering. I personally wouldn’t use an 8-bit microcontroller to interface with my aircraft. I would use something more commercial.

Comment: You should try doing your own research the way most people do when they want to learn something new. Try some different search terms, like "microcontroller" and "reliable" and "spacecraft" and  "life support". Come back when you have a **specific** question

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok thanks alot, but shall I just leave the question or flag it or do what until I get a specific question ?

Comment: @Shams: You can leave it. If it gets closed the system will delete it after a while. Meanwhile you may get a few more comments that give you some guidance.

Comment: @ShamsEl-Deen When they landed on the moon in 60s, the microchips used in spacecraft that time were inferior to the one in your question.

Comment: @user1999 This is a really vague statement. In what way were they inferior? This question is about reliability, and I would argue that those Apollo microcircuits had **far superior** reliability to any common commercial product.

Comment: Basically there are 3 major things to consider: suitability of the microcontroller internal hardware, EMI immunity and suitability of the software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a whole industry of reliability engineering which is how safety-critical electronics (and everything else) is made.

Amongst many other things, most chip manufacturers have special versions of their products which are specified for military, aerospace, medical and safety control purposes.  This starts with simple things like extended temperature ranges.  But the difference between these and ordinary products is mostly one of testing and certification, sometimes to the point where parts have individual serial numbers.  You can imagine that such parts -- even if they run the identical code at identical speed -- are much more expensive that the kind for ordinary commercial products.  As illustration, a given chip design might be rated with a particular clock rate, and perhaps the manufacturer tests 1 part every 10,000 to check it really does.  They might sell you parts where each one has been numbered and tested and give you a certificate with it.  The testing and tracking costs money.  Another point of difference is doing something to make the part more reliable: such as using different packaging materials which have less background radiation, or [radiation-hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening) the device; all this prevents some of the causes of random behaviour of devices.  The functional performance of these devices is unchanged, but you can see how they would be a better choice for safety-critical products.

You may have noticed at the bottom of the Atmel datasheet

> SAFETY-CRITICAL, MILITARY, AND AUTOMOTIVE APPLICATIONS DISCLAIMER: Atmel products are not designed for and will not be used in connection with any applications where the  failure  of  such  products  would  reasonably  be  expected  to  result  in  significant  personal  injury  or  death  (“Safety-Critical  Applications”)  without  an  Atmel  officer's  specific  written consent.  Safety-Critical  Applications  include,  without  limitation,  life  support  devices and systems, equipment or systems for the  operation  of  nuclear  facilities  and  weapons  systems. Atmel products are not designed nor intended for use in military or aerospace applications or environments unless specifically designated by Atmel as military-grade. Atmel products are not designed nor intended for use in automotive applications unless specifically designated by Atmel as automotive-grade.

This is how they tell you these are not specified for safety-critical applications.  All manufacturers have this kind of thing on their datasheets.

The idea is that while the general specification of the part might make it suitable for a given application, it would be negligent to any particular chip in a safety-critical application without special testing.  This is the case whether it's a piece of rope, a screw, or a CPU.

On top of this, there is many design practices, regulations, and certifications of design process which go to make safety-critical engineering.  One place to start is the Wikipedia article [Safety Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_engineering)

Specifically about aircraft, here are a couple articles from Avionics Stack Exchange

- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/52935 8080 in F-16 fighter jet
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/28009 CPUs in airliners

Comment: fix the link to the Wikipedia article, please.

Comment: Already fixed by @BruceAbbot, thanks

Comment: Well... I remember reading something similar from Freescale about not using their MCUs in cars, while most of their customers are car manufacturers and the MCUs are designed specifically for cars. So these disclaimers might just be there to avoid the US parody of a legal system, with lawsuits everywhere. Not necessarily because the MCU is unsuitable.

Comment: The point of my answer was that the functionality of the part is often identical, but the testing it has undergone and the warranty the manufacturer provides is not.